# How to filter dates with a given range from a start and end date?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, momentjs, high-availability

I have a API I'm fetching data from, I want the ability to filter the data by the amount of dates selected like this

Here is a [codesanbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/mystifying-drake-wumye)

[image]

or is it possible to use moment.js to filter by the dates
My json is return in this structure:

```
{
"id": "2",
"postUrl": "https://dogtime.com/assets/uploads/2018/10/puppies-cover-1280x720.jpg",
"profileUrl": "",
"textContent": "The post content goes here. Default allows for three lines before content is truncated. User can click in this area to expand to see the entire post…",
"likeCount": 10,
"commentCount": 10,
"username": "Rex",
"postType": "",
"platform": "INSTAGRAM",
"postTarget": "DEPARTMENT_OF_VA",
"postTopic": "customer_service",
"postDate": "2020-04-25T00:00:00",
"interaction": 10,
"sentiment": 0.5,
"hashTags": [
"22aday",
"agentorange"
]
}
```

I thought something like this would work but it haven't so far:
I added different handlers to know which option was selected like this :

```
const handleForLastSevenDays () {
    let result = [];
    for (let i=0; i <7; i++) {
        let d = new Date();
        d.setDate(d.getDate() - i);
        result.push( (d) )
    }

    return(result.join(','));
}
```

Im more focused on all of the selections except `Custom` at the moment

Comment: Seems like you just need a time amount (days would be easiest) then filter the list based on date parsing and date math. I'm not sure what the `handleForLastSevenDays` is supposed to do.

Comment: @DaveNewton I added `handleForLastSevenDays ` and other handlers to know which one was selected. Is there another approach I should take?

Comment: I don't know about "should", but all the behavior is the same--the only thing that's changing is the number of days, which sounds more like a single function that takes an argument of the number of days. This avoids duplicating logic. If the list of ranges changes, e.g., adding "Last 12 Hours", then this approach would need to be modified, but only slightly,  like by using hours instead of days.

Answer (score 1):

You could use external library but for me JS is enough. You could convert every date into timestamp and then use simple math to filter dates that fall into range. Or you can compare datestrings. It's feels odd, but they could be compared the same way.

Something like this

```
const handleForLastSevenDays = (currenDate) => {
  let d = new Date();
  d.setDate(d.getDate() - 7)
  let sevenDays = d.toJSON();

 return sevenDays > currenDate
}
```

and it best practice to work with dates with timezone. So convert all dates into UTC time.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you could do it.

```js
const { useState, useEffect } = React;

const getDates = () => [
  moment().subtract(12, 'hours').toDate(),
  moment().subtract(3, 'days').toDate(),
  moment().subtract(10, 'days').toDate(),
  moment().subtract(20, 'days').toDate(),
  moment().subtract(45, 'days').toDate(),
  moment().subtract(13, 'months').toDate()
]

const filters = [{
  id: 1,
  text: 'Last 24 Hours',
  params: [24, 'hours']
},{
  id: 2,
  text: 'Last 7 days',
  params: [7, 'days']
},{
  id: 3,
  text: 'Last 14 days',
  params: [14, 'days']
},{
  id: 4,
  text: 'Last 30 days',
  params: [30, 'days']
},{
  id: 5,
  text: 'Last 90 days',
  params: [30, 'days']
},{
  id: 6,
  text: 'Last 12 months',
  params: [12, 'months']
}]

const App = () => {
  const [dates, setDates] = useState(getDates())
  const [options, setOptions] = useState(filters);
  const [option, setOption] = useState(1);
  const [filteredDates, setFilteredDates] = useState([]);

  const onChange = ({target: {value}}) => {
    setOption(Number(value));
  }
  
  useEffect(() => {
    
    const optionObj = options.find(pr => pr.id === option);
    const currentDate = moment();
    const certainDate = moment().subtract(optionObj.params[0], optionObj.params[1]);
    const filteredDates = dates.filter(pr => pr > certainDate);
  
    setFilteredDates(filteredDates);
  }, [option])

  return <div>
    <select onChange={onChange}>
      {options.map(pr => <option key={pr.id} value={pr.id}>{pr.text}</option>)}
    </select>
    {filteredDates.map(date => <div key={date}>{date.toString()}</div>)}
  </div>
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <App />,
    document.getElementById('root')
  );
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.26.0/moment.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: I might be missing it, but how does this update the data being displayed in the `TopPost` component

Comment: The most important logic is in `useEffect` callback. Here i get option object, compute past date from its value and use it to filter array

Comment: can you provide a `codesandbox` please. I'm having trouble plugging in what you wrote and what I have in my sandbox

Comment: I saw your code and I think you should turn your `Dropdown`  `TopPost` components into presentational components. `Dropdown` would have `onChange`, `options` props and  `TopPost`  `items` prop. As for now you are keeping state in many places.